# Difficulties creating minimum and maximum range attributes off a numeric column

Tags: r

In my dataset, I have a column for average household income off which I am trying to create minimum and maximum range columns for the purpose of joining to another table. Only one of the greater than 200 records in the dataset didn’t map properly to a minimum and maximum, and for the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code:

```
mcd$AvgIncHHMinRange <- ifelse(mcd$INC.HH <= '10000', '0', ifelse(mcd$INC.HH > '10000' & mcd$INC.HH <= '20000', '10001', ifelse(mcd$INC.HH > '20000' & mcd$INC.HH<= '30000', '20001', ifelse(mcd$INC.HH > '30000', '30001', '0'))))

mcd$AvgIncHHMaxRange <- ifelse(mcd$INC.HH <= '10000', '10000', ifelse(mcd$INC.HH > '10000' & mcd$INC.HH <= '20000', '20000', ifelse(mcd$INC.HH > '20000' & mcd$INC.HH <= '30000', '30000', ifelse(mcd$INC.HH > '30000', '999999', '10000'))))
```

Here is what I end up with (filtered to income of $10K or below):

```
HH.INC: 5795;
AvgIncHHMinRange: 30001;
AvgIncHHMaxRange: 999999
```

Obviously $5,793 is not between $30,001 and $999,999. Can anybody identify where I went wrong? I re-read the code literally 30 times. Also, I made sure the income column was data type numeric immediately after reading it into R. Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compare character strings rather than numbers. If your data is in character format, convert it to numeric, then remove all the quotations from your `ifelse` so that you are comparing numbers rather than character strings.

Comment: You might also like to look at `cut`.  e.g. `cut(mcd$INC.HH, breaks = c(0:3 * 10000, Inf), labels = c(0:3 * 10000), include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: Bingo. Always something simple. Thank you so much.